# Weird Diagram in Knot Theory

Tags: knot-theory

Can anyone make sense of fig 4.8?

$\hskip 0.5in$ [image: knot]

([Google books link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KXAS3KRZGRMC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=livingston+knot+theory+fig.+4.8&source=bl&ots=OwgFXLvms1&sig=wclsVZoSMCPZbfU7GG7lz6QJa44&hl=en&ei=8aS5TpLOLsey8gOUuq3aBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Comment: If you're going to ask about a picture it'd be courteous to actually post it instead of simply link it. Moreover, which pages in a book GB allows one to preview can change from time to time, so such hyperlinks are temperamental. @percusse: Why did you edit *out* the link?

Comment: You are missing a verb in the question. Looks like if you pull the top loose end through the helix, you can rearrange to create a double helix.

Comment: Sorry @anon . Looks like we have resonated for the image inclusion :)

Comment: Did you get a loop of string and try for yourself? ;)

Comment: Some [color](http://i.imgur.com/5TTwf.png) might help. Note the number of cross-overs between left and right side changes between the two.

Comment: Ok, I know what the diagram means now. Thanks.

Comment: What is the etiquette on what i should do now i have an answer. I can't accept an answer because technically (officially) I don't have one.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. That way, if anybody else is having the same or similar problem, you will have helped them out.